# nest bull separate process for queues and api

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, bull.js

I have a `nestjs` application which is exposing a few REST `API`s.  One of the `API`s triggers a  job which processes some tasks. The problem is that when the job gets triggered the application stops serving REST requests which leads to health check failures from load balancer. I followed the method given at the end of the [README](https://github.com/nestjsx/nest-bull) to start a separate child process for processing jobs. But, the job doesn't start in a child process and the `API` requests stall.

Here's my Job:

```
import {
  BullQueueEvents,
  OnQueueActive,
  OnQueueEvent,
  Process,
  Processor,
} from 'nest-bull';
import { Job } from 'bull';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AService } from './a-service';
import { AJobInterface } from '../AJobInterface';

@Processor({ name: 'a_queue' })
export class AJob {
  private readonly logger = new Logger('AQueue');

  constructor(private readonly service: AService) {}

  @Process({
    name: 'app',
    concurrency: 1
  })
  processApp(job: Job<AJobInterface>) {
    console.log('CHILD: ', process.pid);
    const { jobId } = job.data;
    return this.service.process(jobId);
  }

  @OnQueueActive()
  onActive(job: Job) {
    this.logger.log(
      `Processing job ${job.id} of type ${job.name} with data ${JSON.stringify(
        job.data,
      )}...`,
    );
  }

  @OnQueueEvent(BullQueueEvents.COMPLETED)
  onCompleted(job: Job) {
    this.logger.log(
      `Completed job ${job.id} of type ${job.name} with result ${job.returnvalue}`,
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my app.module.ts:

```
import { Module, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { DatabaseModule } from './db/module';
import { BullModule } from 'nest-bull';
import { AJob } from './worker/a-job';
import { AService } from './worker/a-service';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    DatabaseModule,
    BullModule.register({
      name: 'a_queue',
      processors: [ join(__dirname, 'worker/a-job.js') ],
      options: {
        redis: {
          host: process.env.REDIS_URL || '127.0.0.1',
          port: 6379,
          showFriendlyErrorStack: true,
        },
        settings: {
          lockDuration: 300000,
          stalledInterval: 300000
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, AJob, AService],
})
export class AppModule implements OnModuleInit {
  onModuleInit() {
    console.log('MAIN: ', process.pid);
  }
}
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sorry for posting the answer so late. It turns out that the setup of having a worker in a child process was not possible. I ended up having a separate `worker.module.ts` and a separate `worker.ts` and creating two separate processes for API and worker.

`worker.module.ts`:

```
import { Module, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';
import { DatabaseModule } from '../db/module';
import { BullModule } from 'nest-bull';
import { AJob } from './a-job';
import { AService } from './a-service';
import { join } from 'path';
import { Job, DoneCallback } from 'bull';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    DatabaseModule,
    BullModule.register({
      name: 'a_queue',
      processors: [ (job: Job, done: DoneCallback) => { done(null, job.data); } ],
      options: {
        redis: {
          host: process.env.REDIS_URL || '127.0.0.1',
          port: 6379,
          password: process.env.REDIS_PWD,
          showFriendlyErrorStack: true,
        },
        settings: {
          lockDuration: 300000,
          stalledInterval: 300000
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AppService, AJob, AService],
})
export class WorkerModule implements OnModuleInit {
  onModuleInit() {
    console.log('WORKER: ', process.pid);
  }
}
```

`worker.ts`:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { WorkerModule } from './worker/worker.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(WorkerModule);
  app.init();
}

bootstrap();
```

While `app.module.ts` now looks like this:

```
//...imports
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    DatabaseModule,
    BullModule.register({
      name: 'a_queue',
      processors: [ ],
      options: {
        redis: {
          host: process.env.REDIS_URL || '127.0.0.1',
          port: 6379,
          showFriendlyErrorStack: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule implements OnModuleInit {
  onModuleInit() {
    console.log('MAIN: ', process.pid);
  }
}
```

and the corresponding `app.ts`:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { port } from './config';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(port);
}

bootstrap();
```

Comment: dumb question but: how do you start both `worker.ts` and `app.ts` with next cli?

I mean, if i do `npm start`, only main.ts is executed. 
I could not find how to pass the entry point to nest cli. Somehing like `npm start -entry-point worker.ts`
Or did you move to a 'monorepo' config in `nest-cli`.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @JesusMonzonLegido you can use something like pm2 or supervisor to spin up next process

Comment: @ujwaldhakal thanks. Yes, I had it integrated it with pm2. For development, I had 2 `nest-cli.json` files with different "entryFile" . I started each with something like `NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch --config nest-cli-worker.json`